# Different video formats makes differences to Gist descriptor and classifier?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I’m working on dataset that is made of avi videos and I want to apply Gist on its frames and use Gist features of each frames for training my classifier to recognize actions. If I convert this videos to mp4 format and then perform Gist what will be the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mpeg4 is just a container, it says nearly nothing about how the actual data is compressed. In short - if you use lossy compression then Gist descriptors will change, if you use lossless then they will be the same, and since most common default video compressors are lossy, your Gist will most probably change.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I've used lossy compressor.
do you think gist features of MP4 is useful is useful for training classifier or I should use the features of avi videos?

Comment: It is impossible to answer if it is "useful". Unless compression was very aggressive - probably yes, although all "algorithmical" compression method tend to create artifacts which might be quite bad for vision methods (for example block based compression, if applied with high strength, creates lots of horizontal and vertical edges which are not present in original image)